# how to convert REST call related to Curl command into java client?

Tags: java, rest, curl, httpclient, multipartform-data

```
curl -v 
 -F "sharedsecret=YourIntegrationPassword" 
 -F "content=@BatchDataFile.zip;type=application/octet-stream" 
 -F "event=Import Batch Data" 
 -F clienttype="Curl" -F clientinfo="OS=Linux:Host=myhost" -F clientversion="1.0" 
 https://www.sample.com/sell/fileupload?realm=YourSiteID
```

I was successful in calling the above REST Call by using curl command on linux terminal. Now, I want to call the service (REST Server) using Java RESTClient. How to do this?

Comment: Why don't you start with a basic code for java REST client, and show us the problem you are having with the code.

Comment: I already developed a service and a client, but I am not able to convert this curl related stuff into a Client program. (Thanks for the reply).  By using this service I need to send a zip file to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lightweight curl wrapper API available for java. 
Check it out: [CurlJava](https://github.com/pjlegato/curl-java)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have Spring dependency, then take a look at [Consuming RESTful webservice](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply sidgate,  I figured it out by using Jersey " FormDataMultiPart ".

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own java Rest client ,
from that code you can call your rest .

public class ClientJerseyGet {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Client client = Client.create();
        String restUrl="https://www.sample.com/sell/fileupload?realm=YourSiteID";
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(restUrl);

        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml")
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

        System.out.println("Server response : " + response.getStatus());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(output);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

for more Details you can follow :http://entityclass.in/rest/jerseyClientGetXml.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;

public class AribaClient {

    public static void main(String argsp[]) {

        AribaClient clientRequest = new AribaClient();

        clientRequest.getResponse();
    }

    private void getResponse() {
        try {

            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client
                    .resource("https://www.sample.com/sell/fileupload?realm=YourSiteID");

            FormDataMultiPart formData = new FormDataMultiPart();
            formData.field("name", "value");
            formData.field("file", "D:/repository/moved Files/Purchase.zip");
            formData.field("name1", "value1");

            ClientResponse response = webResource.type(
                    MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(
                    ClientResponse.class, formData);

            // ClientResponse response =
            // webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class,
            // formData);
            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Response :: " + response.getStatus());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the way i am able to post form values to a REST server.